# Magento Go - Adding attribute above product description in Grid view

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-go

Im wanting to add the Brand name (or designer name in this case which i have made a new attribute for) just above the product description in the Category view (grid) but cant figure it out.

As its Magento Go i have no access to the code, other than XML updates for the category itself.

Ive looked everywhere and would value any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are cant get to the template phtml codes, you can put it on by admin.

Open catalog / attributes / manage attributes, find your attribute and in the properties set to

Visible on Product View Page on Front-end
Used in Product Listing

But it will not be on position you want.

You can edit CSS for the template and set an absolute position for your attribute.

Next way is to add in the admin in category XML layout, but this you need to do for each category. (Custom Layout Update)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I have done what you said and set the attribute to yes for "Visible on Product View Page" and "Used in Product Listing" but it is still not visible. Do I need to add any XML to the category? If so what would that be. Thanks

Comment: Hope you can help Martin